# What is "define" in RequireJS?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

What is `define` in RequireJS?  Is it a constructor or a function or...?

1. Create module app. Before create module it loads module app2. After initialize callback:

   ```
   define(
       'app',
       ['app2'],
       function( app2 ){
           console.log(app2)
       }
   );
   ```
2. What's this syntax?

   ```
   define(function (require) {
       var logger = require("./app2");
       console.log(logger);
   });
   ```
3. And this:

   ```
   define({
       color: "black",
       size : "large"
   });
   ```

Comment: Here's a good starting point: http://requirejs.org/

Answer (score 0):

From the comments:

```
 The function that handles definitions of modules. Differs from
 require() in that a string for the module should be the first argument,
 and the function to execute after dependencies are loaded should
 return a value to define the module corresponding to the first argument's
 name.
```

And its signature is:

```
define = function (name, deps, callback)
```

In javascript every function is a Function object, so in both cases you are passing to `define` an object.

```
//Allow for anonymous modules
if (typeof name !== 'string') {
    //Adjust args appropriately
    callback = deps;
    deps = name;
    name = null;
}
```