# Defining a module in ES6 or rather reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, requirejs

I'm having trouble understanding how define() function of requireJS works.

I have initialized a reactjs project with create-react-app and from spring tutorial copied the define() function (it's at the bottom). I did read [related questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27195500/what-is-define-in-requirejs)  and define() [definition in amdjs-api](https://github.com/amdjs/amdjs-api/wiki/AMD) however I still don't understand how to make it work with react app and whether it needs es6 implementation or its related to reactjs.

So basically I'm not even sure whats the problem, but the error I'm getting is:

> error    'define' is not defined                        no-undef

```
define(function(require) {
'use strict';

  var interceptor = require('rest/interceptor');

  return interceptor({
        request: function (request) {
            if (request.path.indexOf('{') === -1) {
                return request;
            } else {
                request.path = request.path.split('{')[0];
                return request;
            }
        }
 });

});
```

Comment: Where is that error coming from? It looks like a linting error. Try adding `/* global define:false */` to the top of the file.

Comment: You are confusing AMD with CommonJS, Create React App relies on Webpack and [CommonJS](https://webpack.github.io/docs/commonjs.html)/[ES6 module syntax.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export) They do not use `define` function for defining a module.

Comment: ok, so define basically implements global variable/function, yes? whats the best way to to do it in es6? export I assume? or maybe  module.exports?